# Pinterest integration with android app - Pinning Video

Tags: android, pinterest

And now I'm trying to integrate PinIt with my app using Android Pin It SDK and It works wonderfully as expected. I can now Pin a image. It was easy though. But how can I pin a video from my application? The URL below opens in a browser. It works fine. But I want to do this from my app

```
http://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?media=http://images.frandroid.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Test-LG-Nexus-4-Gauche.png&url=http://vimeo.com/52397255&is_video=true&title=Jingit+Intro&description=Nexus%204
```

just like how I pin an image using the following code

```
PinItButton pinIt = (PinItButton) findViewById(R.id.pin_it);
pinIt.setImageUrl("http://placekitten.com/400/300");
pinIt.setUrl("http://placekitten.com"); // optional
pinIt.setDescription("A place kitten!"); // optional
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
PinItButton pinIt = (PinItButton) findViewById(R.id.pin_it);
pinIt.setImageUrl("http://images.frandroid.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Test-LG-Nexus-4-Gauche.png");
pinIt.setUrl("http://vimeo.com/52397255");
pinIt.setDescription("Nexus 4");
pinIt.doPinIt(this);
```

Comment: Yup. That's correct.. Waiting for someone to answer to award the bouty.